# Php function to extract hyperlink from string

Tags: php, hyperlink, extract

I need the function for extract link from html string.
Example:

String:

```
<!-- BEGIN PARTNER PROGRAM - DO NOT CHANGE THE PARAMETERS OF THE HYPERLINK -
-> <a href='http://www.link.com' target='_blank'>text</a> <img 
src='http://www.linkimage.com' BORDER='0' WIDTH='1' HEIGHT='1' /> <!-- END 
PARTNER PROGRAM -->
```

need to extract:

```
http://www.link.com
```

Thx

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-extract-html-links-with-regular-expression/

Comment: Fails the obligatory "what have you tried and where are you stuck?" question... hint: don't use a [RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) but [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "<!-- BEGIN PARTNER PROGRAM - DO NOT CHANGE THE PARAMETERS OF THE HYPERLINK -
-> <a href='http://www.link.com' target='_blank'>text</a> <img 
src='http://www.linkimage.com' BORDER='0' WIDTH='1' HEIGHT='1' /> <!-- END 
PARTNER PROGRAM --> ";

    $link = explode('<a href=\'', $string)[1];
    $link = explode('\'',$link)[0];
    echo $link;

    $linkimage = explode('src=\'', $string)[1];
    $linkimage = explode('\'',$linkimage)[0];
    echo $linkimage;
```

Comment: If there's an `<a>` tag in there like `<a target="_blank" href="...">...</a>` this will fail.

Comment: @Pau Do you want to do this for multiple different strings? It is important if the other string have the exact same pattern. The code for extraction is based on the pattern. To obtain linkimage: replace the first parameter in explode with `src=\'` and the seconds stays the same.

Comment: The string have always same pattern

Comment: @CD001 If the string always have this pattern, it'll work

Comment: @Pau if this was correct, you should mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @TeoMihaila donde ! How could i extract from same srting `http://www.linkimage.com`

Comment: @Pau Check the answer. I have modified it

Answer (score 0):

the quick n dirty way:

```
preg_match_all('~href=([\'"])([^\'"]+)\\1~is', $htmlString, $matches); 

print_r($matches[2]);
```

the proper way:

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php / http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php and so on..

Problem with proper way is that you need to tidy the html before parsing. In some cases even the php native http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php fails to do that correctly.